# Function that matches a value to value or array (better way to write it)

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes 2 arguments, first is a value and second can be a value or an array.
It checks if first argument is equal to second, or (if its an array), if it's equal to one of array's elements.

```
function matchType(value, type) {        
    if (Array.isArray(type)) {
        for (t of type) {
            if (value == t) {
                return value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (value == type) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then it works like:

> matchType("foo", "foo")
>
> "foo"
>
> matchType("foo", ["foo", "bar"])
>
> "foo"
>
> matchType("foo", ["blah", "bar"])
>
> null

What's a more elegant way to write this function, preferably in functional style? ES6 or lodash are fine to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an array for checking and use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for the check and return either the value or `null`.

```js
function matchType(value, type) {        
    return [].concat(type).includes(value)
        ? value
        : null;
}

console.log(matchType("foo", "foo")); // "foo"
console.log(matchType("foo", ["foo", "bar"])); // "foo"
console.log(matchType("foo", ["blah", "bar"])); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can depend on `type` being an array, you can simply return `value` immediately if it's `===` to `type`, otherwise use the conditional operator and return `value` if type  `includes` it:

```js
function matchType (value, type) {
  if (value === type) return value;
  return type.includes(value)
  ? value
  : null;
}
console.log(matchType("foo", "foo"));
console.log(matchType("foo", ["foo", "bar"]));
console.log(matchType("foo", ["blah", "bar"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

First - use ES6's array's `includes()` - [here's the MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).
Second, you can short the fnction to an one line using `&&`, `||` and `... ? ... : ...`:

```
function matchType(value, type) {
  var toReturnValue = false;
  toReturnValue = Array.isArray(type) ? type.includes(value) : value === type;
  return toReturnValue ? value : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach using Ramda:

```js
const matchType =
  R.ifElse(R.contains,
    R.nthArg(0),
    R.always(null));

console.log(matchType("foo", "foo"));
console.log(matchType("foo", ["foo", "bar"]));
console.log(matchType("foo", ["blah", "bar"]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```